# How to call to a method that is in the MainActivity from another class

Tags: android

I want to call a method that is in my MainActivity class and I don't know how to do it if I want to call it in another class. How can I do it?

Comment: What type of class are your trying to call it from, another `Activity`, hosted `Fragment`, or some other?

Comment: You were unable to find any information, SO questions, or documentation about this? Also, no need to say thanks or that you are a beginner, we can tell from the question and it is not adding anything useful.

Comment: @VeneetReddy I have public void actualitzaTitol() { ... } in the MainActivity and I just want to call this method in another class

Comment: You can call a method from another class if its a static method

Comment: @Sepehr yes I tried, but the function that is inside my method can't be referenced in a static function :(

Comment: Can you post `MainActivity` and where you are trying to call it from?

Answer (score 1):

you can call it using the main activity context this might help : [Calling method of another class using contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635086/calling-method-of-another-class-using-contexts)

Comment: As I said, I have a function inside my method that can't be referenced in a static function.

Comment: I updated my answer it looks like you can call the activity by passing the context